# Contour Integral around square

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Calculate the following around a square of side-length 4 centered on the origin, with sides parallel to the coordinate axes:

$$\quad \quad \oint \frac{\sin(z)dz}{z^2(1+z^2)}$$

I think I would have to apply Cauchy's Residue Theorem but I am not sure?

Comment: Sure, you can apply the residue theorem. Now outline your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The residue theorem should work.  You have simple poles at $0$ and $\pm i$.

Compute the residues, add them up, and multiply by $2\pi i$.

I get a residue of $1$ at $0$.  And $\dfrac{-\sin i}{2i}$ at $\pm i$.

Thus we get $2\pi i(1-\dfrac {2\sin i}{2i})=2\pi i-2\pi\sin i$.

Comment: One correction: $z = 0$ is also a simple pole.

Comment: Oh yeah.  My mistake.  @Maxim

Comment: @ChrisCuster How did you find the residue of the $z=i$ case.

Comment: $\lim_{z\to i}(z-i)f(z)$, where $f(z)=\dfrac{\sin z}{z^2(z^2+i)}$.

Comment: Typo:  $f(z)=\dfrac {\sin z}{z^2(z^2+1)}$.